# Clipbucket No Video Found though upload succeed and I have .MP4 file under /var/www/html/files/videos/

Tags: php, mysql, clipbucket

I have installed the clip-bucket on LAMP officially though the contents there are missing `cb_users` table when creating the website, but I manually create the table and created the admin user and I  can login to my website, but when I upload  the video to the website it succeed and I clicked the submit button, but I couldn't find the video from website.

It exists in server directory with 777 permission

Answer (score 0):

Hi there this issue comes when you try to install `clipbucket` with sql strict mode on.
Turn off `sql_strict` mode and try reinstalling `clipbucket` everything will be fine after that even videos will start appearing too.

Here is how you can turn off sql strict mode.
go to `phpmyadmin` click on sql tab and run this query

```
set global sql_mode=""
```

Comment: I did what you have suggested,it looks like ok initially. whereas when I uploaded some video with wmv ,mp4 and avi it succeed but go back to my homepage  it still shows nothing, but from account portal i can see it and it passed the conversion with succeed, but it just didnt show up and a weird thing is when I click upload video it will redict to .../video which is not exist in my server should be video.php and the same for other pages , when I click edit it doesnt allow me to edit.with You cannot edit this video

Comment: It looks i cant add user though it replies with succeed but when I check database, only admin user there no other user at all

Comment: it redirects you to /video because you have turned on your seo urls in clipbucket.also please activate the video so that it will show up into clipbucket home.

Comment: Thank you for  the advice on seo ones it works. But the video just didnt show up in my homepage whenever I turn on/off video activation checks.